# AJAX form only reloads the page

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I've looked up various explanations for using ajax with forms, and have stripped the entire program down to just getting the form to talk with the php, but it's being unreasonably stubborn...

The form:

```
<form method="get" action="">
Name:<input type="text" name="uname" id="uname"><br>';
<input type="submit" onclick="addcomment()" value="Post">
</form> 
<a href="" onclick="addcomment()">Test</a>
```

The javascript:

```
function addcomment()
    {

         if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                { xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();}
            else
                { xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");}

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                    document.write(xmlhttp.responseText);
                    }
                   }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","test.php",true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

The PHP:

```
<?php
echo 'test';
?>
```

It doesn't pass any information, and should only write 'test' across the screen, but instead, it reloads the html page, adding on the `'get'` `information(test.html?uname=)`. This works fine from an anchor tag, unless I try it after trying the form(ie, with the `'get'` information added to the page name). I'm sure I'm missing something basic. Can you help me?

Thank you.

P.S. I can't use jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return false from the add comment function to tell the browser not to execute the default action of posting the form. What is happening at the moment is the browser is executing you function then immediately submitting the form giving the xmlhttprequest no time to execute.

Comment: Yep, that was the ridiculous thing I was forgetting. Thank you. It's missing things like this that end up taking hours of my time. Sad...

Answer (score 1):

You need to prevent the browser from submitting the form to the page. This is done by `returning false` to the script. Example:

```
<form method="get" action="" onsubmit="addcomment(); return false;">
    Name: <input type="text" name="uname" id="uname"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Post" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you, I knew return false, but I wasn't aware of preventDefault(). I'll look it up.